# What are some good lower bounds on the consistency of the failure of the PCF conjecture?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, large-cardinals, inner-model-theory, pcf-theory

Shelah's celebrated theorem states that $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$.

But the conjecture is that $\omega_4$ can be provably replaced by $\omega_1$. Namely, $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_1}$ holds, assuming that $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal.

As far as I understand it, we know that from large cardinal assumptions it is consistent that $2^{\aleph_\omega}$ is arbitrarily large below $\aleph_{\omega_1}$ (and it is a strong limit, of course). But there is no current way to go beyond $\aleph_{\omega_1}$. Even Gitik's work on the subject does not translate to the $\aleph_n$'s.

> **Question.** Suppose that the PCF Conjecture fails. Namely, $\aleph_\omega$ is a strong limit cardinal, but $2^{\aleph_\omega}>\aleph_{\omega_1}$. What kind of large cardinals can we expect to find in inner models?

(Of course large cardinals are necessary, since $2^{\aleph_\omega}>\aleph_{\omega+1}$ with $\aleph_\omega$ as a strong limit was shown by Gitik to be equiconsistent with the existence of a measurable $\kappa$ of Mitchell order $\kappa^{++}$.)

Comment: Of course, any corrections to what I understand is also welcomed.

Comment: A title informative about the topic (not only for specialized people) would be useful

Comment: YCor, I'm all in favor of informative titles, but I'm not sure what would be more informative? The PCF Conjecture is a fairly common term.

Comment: What are the best bounds you know already? From Gitik's work on SCH it follows that $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_{\omega+1}$ (with $\aleph_\omega$ a strong limit) is equiconsistent with a measurable cardinal $\kappa$ of Mitchell order $\kappa^{++}$. I'm guessing you already know this? It's probably worth mentioning in the question. It's hard to know what you would call a "good" bound without first knowing what you might consider an "everybody-already-knows-that" bound.

Comment: @Will: Yes, but this is just $2^{\aleph_\omega}=\aleph_{\omega+2}$. We are talking about significantly larger gaps here. Good bounds include Woodin cardinals, or proper class of strong cardinals, or a sequence of $\omega_1+1$ strong cardinals, or whatever. I'm understand there is some ambiguity in "good lower bound", but obviously Gitik's initial result about SCH is *not* that.

Comment: This is a good question. I don't think we know much about it yet. Something along the lines of the Gitik-Schindler-Shelah paper seems to be the state of the art.

Comment: @Andrés: Do you mean the one from 2002 about PCF theory and Woodin cardinals?

Comment: Yes, that one.$ $

Comment: Shelah has a lot of results that treat  pcf assumptions themselves kind of like large cardinal statements.  A typical result might show that a combinatorial statement implies a pcf statement, and from the pcf statement one can force the combinatorial statement, with the pcf statement being something currently intractable.

Comment: With regard to the specific question, my understanding is that it's still not clear if the obstacle to moving things down to $\aleph_\omega$  is a matter of insufficient technology, or something deeper lurking beneath the surface.

Comment: @Todd: Yes, and I am just wondering what are the current known bounds on the failure at $\aleph_\omega$. Do we know it at least implies the many strong cardinals needed for Gitik's work? (Or, as I initially hoped before your last comment, do we know that it requires even more?) Thanks for the two comments by the way!

Answer (score 7):

It follows from the work of Gitik and Mitchell [Indiscernible sequences for extenders, and the singular cardinal hypothesis](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168007296000073) that the hypothesis implies the existence of an inner model with overlapping extenders.

As explained in the comments by Andres, it follows from the work of
Gitik, Schindler and Shelah [Pcf theory and
Woodin cardinals](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0211433) that one can get $PD$ (Projective Determinacy).

It seems that the results of the above paper are currently the best ones.

Comment: What do overlapping extenders give us? If my memory serves me right, certain level of strongness?

Comment: Yes. In fact in the paper, Theorem 3.24 they show that  there is a sharp for a model with a
strong cardinal.

Comment: Well, this is very nice. I'm surprised that we don't have the machinery to prove something like $\mathsf{AD}^{L(\Bbb R)}$ from these hypotheses, seeing how we do get $\sf PD$.